# Who will be the last modified by for Workflow rule or Triggers

Tags: trigger, workflow

When the field was updated by a workflow rule or triggers, who will be the last modified by or edited by on the history? What about the scenario when the update is performed by time-based workflow rule?

Answer (score 1):

The user who edited the record that caused all of the triggers/workflow rules to fire

Comment: Unless the user is inactive, in which case it will be the default workflow user.